# Indesign Script. How to automatically place (18) images from a file into (18) rectangular grids?

Tags: javascript, jsx, adobe, adobe-indesign

Hi I work at a custom photo album retail store. I'm responsible for printing out the albums with inDesign.

Our current system for processing photo albums is to manually place (18) images into an inDesign template with (18) rectangular grids.

Attached below is what the inDesign template looks like.

I want to create a script that either:

- Automatically places selected images from a file into (18) rectangular grids.
- Arranges selected selected pictures from a file into (18) rectangular grids.

Any advice or resources would be appreciated.

I found a script that does something similar to what I need, however it is outdated and requires editing to fit our needs.

https://github.com/johnwun/js4ai/blob/master/distributeStackedObjects.jsx?fbclid=IwAR2tfutFmjcKJ-V7D88TDPn-lPN_MN9OeXOkaLQ0IAlUNo-OoAFPJQu_YiU

I've tried to edit the linked script however, it is out my skill level.

Comment: It can be done with a script but the solution depends on what exactly you have and what you're trying to get. Please, show your template (it absents in your question) and what the desired output looks like.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the template you referred to so I can only generalize my comment. I have been successful doing this using the date merge tool in InDesign. With some initial trial and error you can create a template of your layout once and only have to so a couple of steps for each new album. The limitation here is that you are stuck with a evenly spaced grid of images. This works great for *hundreds of images* as the setup time is negligible compared to the time it would take to place them by hand.

**BUT**

For 18 images I can't think of an automated solution that could be quicker than the place tool.

- File > Place
- Select your 18 images from the folder they are in
  (*CTRL + A* **OR** *CTRL + Click* to select multiple)
- This loads ***all*** the images onto the cursor and all you have to do is click
  each frame to place each one. There is even a thumbnail on the cursor so you know
  which one you are placing if the order matters.

I hope this helps.